# What is the preferred way of including variables into strings in python 3?

Tags: string, python-3.x, variables

I am a beginner Python programmer, and I'm using Python 3.6, and as I learned from multiple resources, I have noticed that there are different ways to include a variable into a string or print statement.

- I know about adding strings and variables:

  ```
  name = "Brian"
  age = 20
  print("Hello " + name + " I see you are " + str(age) + " years old.")
  ```
- I know about using commas to intermix variables and strings:

  ```
  print("Hello", name, "I see you are", age, "years old.")
  ```
- I also know about the .format function:

  ```
  print("Hello {} I see you are {} years old.".format(name, age))
  ```

  My question is, which one of these is the preferred way to do it by Python programmers? And are there any differences between these methods and when to use them?

Comment: Python is designed to be expressive. In other words, choose what you like.

Comment: Like what @TCouch said, choose what you like. Give them all a try and see which you prefer. However, I generally see people using your first example (I personally choose this method).

Answer (score 1):

Dan's Python String Formatting Rule of Thumb:
If your format strings are user-supplied, use Template Strings to avoid security issues.
Otherwise, use Literal String Interpolation if you're on Python 3.6+, and "New Style" String Formatting if you're not.
Quoted from Python Tricks The Book, by Dan Bader.

Answer (score 1):

If using Python 3.6+, you should prefer string literal interpolation.

```
name = "Brian"
age = 20
print(f"Hello {name}, I see you are {age} years old.")
```

Output:

```
"Hello Brian, I see you are 20 years old."
```